# Rotate the map to GPS heading / direction in ArcGIS using ArcObjects SDK 10 for .NET

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, gps, arcgis-engine

Assuming I use ArcGIS or an ArcEngine application on a mobile PC. Is it possible to rotate the map in ArcGIS to the direction the device is travelling using a GPS receiver? If yes, how? I would like to use ArcObjects SDK 10 for .NET to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried them myself, but it looks like the iScreenDisplay interface has rotation functions: [iScreenDisplay](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IScreenDisplay_Interface/001w000002s1000000/)

Also check out `screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.Rotation()`

Might be a good starting point.